# Como saber se uma pessoa fez um clique em uma DIV ou não

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies

Eu tenho anuncio e quero saber se a pessoa já fez um clique no anuncio nos últimos 2 dias.

Se ela já clicou, não aparece mas, se não clicou, ainda aparece.

Algo como isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  setcookie("USER","sim", time() + 172800); // 86400 = 1 dia, 172800 = 2 dia
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE["USER"])): ?>
  <div class="anuncio">
    ANUNCIO PARA QUEM NÃO CLICOU AINDA!
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <div class="">
    OPS, VC JA CLICOU NÃO APARECER ANUNCIO
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Mas, como saber se ele já fez o clique dentro dessa `<div>`, ou seja, se ele já clicou no anuncio

Comment: Você pode usar javascript pra criar um cookie, quando ele clicar no anuncio, e depois verifica se o cookie existe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493716/onclick-javascript-cookie

Comment: Me ajuda ? Não manjo de java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java script com ajax, para carregar a pagina em PHP quando clicar na div!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 function gravaCookieclique() {
  $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "gravacookieclique.php",
   data: { gravaCookieclique: "sim"}
  });
 }
</script>
```

E no PHP coloque sua função com $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução sem PHP e cookie, apenas com JS e LocalStorage:

```
//Elemento do anuncio
const anuncio = document.querySelector('#anuncio');

//Se houver o anuncio salvo
if (localStorage.anuncio) {
  //Cria um objeto de data com o valor salvo
  let data = new Date(localStorage.anuncio);
  //Adiciona dois dias a data criada
  data.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);

  //Compara a data salva com a data atual
  if (data > new Date()) {
    //Se a data salva + 2 dias for maior que a data atual, esconde o anuncio
    anuncio.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

//Adiciona um ouvinte de evento no elemento do anuncio
anuncio.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //Salva em localStorage a data
  localStorage.anuncio = new Date();
});
```

Comment: Não me ajudou.. pq minha pagina tem php também.. ai tipo quero saber se ele clicou.. se já clicou coloco pra mostrar outra pagina..

Comment: De qualquer forma precisará de JS para saber se o usuário clicou ou não no anúncio. É possível fazer sem mas é mais complicado. Obs: nada impede que você use JS junto com PHP

Comment: Vc teria um exemplo de código ? já junto com PHP.

Comment: É só colocar esse código ai em cima dentro das tags `<script> </script>` antes fechar a tag `<body>` e trocar `#anuncio` pelo seletor do seu anúncio

Comment: não funcionou aqui..

Comment: Se possível, adicione na pergunta o código que tentou